# Calculating the size of const char array:

Tags: objective-c, arrays

I have this:

```
const char changedValue [] = {0xCA,0x06,0x03,0x80,0x01,0x00};
```

and I need to calculate the total of the six bytes and add it to the end of that array the checksum of all bytes.

Answer (score 1):

The size of a byte array with six bytes is... six.

If you need to include a (byte-size?) checksum, it must be one byte larger.

Comment: Thanks, I do need to add an additional byte to the end of the array , how would i go about calculating that ? is the question.

Comment: Many checksum algorithms are possible. A very simple one is to XOR all values, i.e. `char checksum = changedValue[0] ^ changedValue[1] ^ ... changedValue[5]; `

Comment: how can we check the changedValue [] count(number of objects in that array)?

Comment: @UttamKumarUtterapally As this is basically a plain old c array, you can't. One option is to put a sentinel item at the end (like 0xFF, if this value is never used), and just count.